# Sugarcrm not a valid entry method

Tags: installation, cpanel, sugarcrm, softaculous

I installed SugarCRM using cpanel softaculous option. I checked and I even asked my hosting about all the requirements of the script. When i try to acces the link where SugarCRM is installed i get the following error:
"Not a valid entry method"
I didn't do any modification in the script, everything is new and clean.
Any idea?

Comment: Is it possible for you to show a screen-shot on the question?

Comment: here is the link, sorry :) http://funteam.ro/thor/

Comment: I presume you're using Apache. Do you have access to the error logs? If so can you include the last few entries here?

Comment: Well, is on a hosting server, not my own. I'll try to look to see if i can find something.

Comment: Your host must be giving you a cpanel. That may contain a link to the logs